# Is it possible to built a split selector in mobile safari/PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, user-interface, mobile-safari

Is it possible to built a split selector in mobile safari? Something similar to the alarm clock time selector where you pick hour, minute and am/pm on the same selector?

Is there something in PhoneGap that would let me do this?

Answer (score 2):

I've used Mobiscroll in my projects and it works quite well...

[Mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com/)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did this satisfy your question?  If not, is there anything else you'd like added?  Thanks,